cat and dog fight
I got a cat around the beginning of October. My boyfriend and I have kept her in our bedroom where she has space and everything she needs. My boyfriend has a dog who is not very comfortable with cats due to a past experience where he got too close to a stray and got smacked.
I went downstairs to let my dog outside to use the restroom and the bedroom door did not latch properly leading to either the dog coming into the room or the cat getting out. The next thing I knew I started to hear hissing and barking. I ran up the stairs as fast as I could and was screaming at his dog; my cat ran into the room before I even made it up the steps.
This happened last night and she has barely come out from under the bed. I’ve tried getting her to come out with food treats, toys, and even a laser pointer but she was not interested. I’m so scared that I did something wrong and I want to know that she is okay. The fight only happened for 15 seconds max and my boyfriend's dog is a pit. I’m not sure what happened. Once again, all I heard was hissing, growling, and barking. If someone has any answers, please tell me I want to make sure that she will be okay. update- today i heard her in my dresser meowing and i assumed she was stuck so i tried to help her a horrid stench came out when i removed one of the drawers and i immediately saw blood i hurried and called an emergency vet and i rushed i got there and her heart was almost stopped so they put her on medicine and put a tube down her throat to help her breathe they did x-rays and they came back clear they released some air in her stomach but as they did that they soon realized realized the air was coming out of her intestines my options were either to put her down or do emergency surgery which we all agreed that putting her down was best do to the state she was in that was the worst thing i’ve gone through but i’m glad she’s in no more pain and that she crossed the rainbow bridge as comfortable as possible although i feel like it was my fault that this got bad i try not to blame myself because i thought she was just scared and in hiding which in the end she just didn’t want me to know she was hurting i wish there was more i could do but sadly there wasn’t i hope she’s happy in kitty heaven running around rest in peace my little tinkerstinker (tinkerbell)

It will probably be ok, your cat just needs some time to calm down again. Excess stimulation like laser pointers or petting her against her will are not helping her, BTW. Give her the time and space she requires and ignore her until she is ready to come out of hiding again.
At some point in time you will have to introduce the dog and the cat. This should not happen by accident, because the dog will think that the cat is an intruder and chase her and the cat will think that the dog is an intruder and be afraid of him.
Instead I suggest one (or both) of you sit down right in the door to the bedroom. You are the living barrier that prevents the dog from entering the room. If he is too excited and you cannot stop him sitting down, have the other person hold him back with a leash.
The one sitting down is supposed to mostly ignore the dog and only interact with the cat. Pet her calmly, if possible. Show the dog that you welcome this cat into your home. She may become afraid and hide, that's ok, let her leave and repeat the same process the next day (and the next, and the next...) until she learns that the dog cannot do her harm.
In the beginning, it's better to keep the dog one arms (or legs) length away by physically blocking him with your arm (or leg) held to his chest. The cat needs to trust that the dog won't harm her. Once she learned that, the risk of her running away (and thereby triggering the dogs hunting instinct) is much lower.

thank you so much this gives me a lot of relief we tried to crack the door and have them just look at each other and sniff and it went really well so we thought that we could take her out while holding her and that didn’t go so well the dog started barking and jumping trying to get my cat it was terrifying i think the cat would be fine with the dog because my dog is always in the room with my cat and they get along fine my boyfriends dog is just insane and he doesn’t listen
